# How to make bootstrap panel height and width with dynamic content

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

[image]

This is my address list of my project and i am rendering the list from backend now i want to make height and width of all the panels same and responsive.

This is my html code

Data in panel is according to what stored in my database These all are the test data

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
   <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
       <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
          <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
             <div class="row ">
                <div class="col-md-12 ">
                  <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
                    <br>
                    <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">
                        198 Commerce Drive,
                    </span>
                <br>
                     Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
                <br>
                Canada
                <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
   <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;">
                     <span class="fa fa-square"></span>
                                Ship To Address
                </button>
                        
             </div>
         </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
             <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721">
               <span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;
                        Edit
              </button>
             </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
               <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
                <span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;
                  Delete
                </button>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're using the fairly old Bootstrap 3 !
Back then, they made the grid system using `float`, which is not possible to achieve what you want. (At least not without using javascript)

One way to do this, is to add a class to the `row` and customize it using flexbox.

```css
.custom-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.custom-row>[class^='col'] {
  float: none;
  height: inherit;
}

.panel {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.panel-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row custom-row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6<br>Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6<br><br>Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping" style="margin-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 10px; display: block;">
    <div class="panel fixed-box" style="border:1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom: 3px;">
      <div class="panel-body fixed-body">
        <address style="margin: -10px 0 1px 0;min-height: inherit;">
          <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <strong style="word-break: break-all">Winnipeg</strong>
              <br>
              <span class="truncate_to_ellipsis" title="198 Commerce Drive">198 Commerce Drive,</span>
              <br>
              Winnipeg, Manitoba, R3P0Z6
              <br>
              Canada
              <br>
            </div>
          </div>
        </address>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
            <button class="form-control btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;width: inherit;"><span class="fa fa-square"></span>Ship To Address</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left addressDiv" style="text-transform: capitalize;" id="address721"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit</button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-left" style="text-transform: capitalize;"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span>&nbsp;Delete</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has removed all `*-xs-*` classes. Use `col-12` instead of `col-xs-12`.

---

Use `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on columns (`col-sm-4 col-xs-12 addressBox-shipping`).

```
.col-sm-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```css
.col-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* You do not need to use this */

.col-4 div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">
        Hello
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">
        Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">
        Possimus sit consequuntur in dicta quia delectus quo atque quidem iste provident voluptatibus officia, alias, quos enim, assumenda beatae. Provident, corporis dignissimos!
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus fugit perferendis veritatis, maiores, iusto in culpa aperiam explicabo consectetur vero, reiciendis quod! Iusto atque maxime reiciendis vero animi voluptates hic.
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 mb-3">
      <div class="bg-primary py-5">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```